# Is std::array<char, size> null terminated?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

Is the following snippet of code safe? It invoked std::string's fourth constructor that takes in a pointer to a null terminated string. The thing is, I'm not sure if `word` below is null terminated. Is it?

```cpp
std::array<char, 4> word{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

int main()
{
    std::string p = word.data();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No.  It is not null-terminated.  To be null-terminated, the array would need 5 characters, the last of which is 0.  You are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: std::string's fourth constructor does not take in a pointer to a null terminated string, it takes in a pointer to char. A developer must care of a null-terminator.

Comment: @S.M. the difference between a pointer to char and a pointer to a null terminated string is all in how the pointer gets used.  The language itself doesn't make a distinction.  You're right that ensuring the null terminator is the developer's responsibility.

Comment: `std::string p(word.begin(), word.end());`

Comment: @Evg This is what I had before, but I was dealing with `std::array<char, 50>`, which had 46 null terminators when converted to a string using `begin` and `end` iterators. Hahah...

Comment: @TeeZadAwk in that case, you could use `std::string p(word.begin(), word.begin()+desired_length)`, or simply `std::string p(word.data, desired_length)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is std::array<char, size> null terminated?

It can contain a null terminated string. It doesn't necessarily contain a null terminated string.

> ```
> std::array<char, 4> word{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
> ```

This array does not contain a null terminated string. You can tell because none of the elements are the null terminator character.

> ```
> std::string p = word.data();
> ```

The behaviour of this program is undefined.

> Is the following snippet of code safe?

No.

---

> how to make word null terminated.

Here is one example:

```
std::array<char, 5> word{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

Or if you want to be more explicit:

```
std::array<char, 5> word{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'};
```

Comment: This answer would be perfect if you included an example of how to make `word` null terminated.

Comment: @MarkRansom I bet I can give an example of how to make `word` null terminated that would make this answer far from perfect.  Bwahahahahahaha ahum.

Comment: @MarkRansom Added.

Comment: And now it's perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This array is non null-terminated. One easy way to make it null-terminated would be to initialize it from `string literal` like that:

```
std::array<char, 5> a{"abcd"};
```

Comment: Interesting how `std::array<int, 5>` does not default initialize the ints in the array to 0, but `std::array<char, 5>` will default initialize all chars to 0. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the following snippet of code safe?

No.  It is invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

> It invoked std::string's fourth constructor that takes in a pointer to a null terminated string. The thing is, I'm not sure if `word` below is null terminated. Is it?

No, it is not.

A simple fix, assuming you don't want to null-terminate the array, would be to use a different `std::string` constructor that takes in the desired length as a parameter, eg:

```cpp
std::array<char, 4> word{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

int main()
{
    std::string p(word.data(), word.size());
    // more generally:
    // std::string p(word.data(), desired_length);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a different `std::string` constructor that takes in iterators instead, eg:

```cpp
std::array<char, 4> word{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

int main()
{
    std::string p(word.begin(), word.end());
    // more generally:
    // std::string p(word.begin(), word.begin() + desired_length);
    return 0;
}
```

Either way, you don't need a null terminator.

Comment: The reason I was thinking about `.data` to begin with was because I didn't want to use `end` and `begin`. Why? Well I had an array with 4 non-null characters, and 46 null terminators (`std::array<char, 50>`). This ends up creating a string of length 50 with 46 null terminators. When this string is the key of a map, you're going to have a bad time... Effectively, "abcd" (1 null terminator) looks the same as "abcd" (46 null terminators), but are completely different keys to a map. https://godbolt.org/z/MKPs7MW4v

Comment: @TeeZadAwk In that case, `std::string p(word.data(), 4);` or `std::string p(word.begin(), word.begin()+4);` would have worked for you.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the exact length of the contents of the array beforehand. In other words, I'm given an array of size 50, but I'm not sure if all the contents are null terminators, some are null terminators, or non are null terminators.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk You can use `std::find()` to check if a null-terminator exists in the array or not. If it does, subtract `begin()` from the result to get its index (or use `std::distance()`), there is your length. If it does not exist, use the array's full size instead, eg: `auto iter = std::find(word.begin(), word.end(), '\0'); size_t length = (iter != word.end()) ? (iter - word.begin()) : word.size(); std::string p(word.data(), length);`

Comment: @TeeZadAwk Or, you could just simplify that using iterators, eg: `std::string p(word.begin(), std::find(word.begin(), word.end(), '\0'));` If a null terminator is found, it will copy only up to the terminator, otherwise it will copy up to the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to initialize the `std::string` with a *null terminated string* in the *std::array* but not over running the bounds, you can use `std::find` like this:

```
std::string p{std::begin(word), std::find(std::begin(word), std::end(word), '\0')};
```

It will initialize either up to the first *null terminator* or the end of the array if there is no *null terminator*.